# ADF Scheduling when existing Job not yet finished

Tags: azure-data-factory, job-scheduling

Having read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution, it is unclear to me if:

- A schedule is made every hr for a job to run,

  - can we stop the concurrent execution of the next job at hr+1 if the job for hr+0 is still running?

    - It looks if concurrency = 1 means this,

      - But is that invocation simply not start until concurrent execution is finished?
      - Or will it be discarded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we set the concurrency 1, only one instance will be allowed to run at a time. When the scheduled trigger runs again and tries to run the pipeline, If the pipeline is already running, the next invocation will be queued. It will start after finishing the current instance.

For your question, the following invocation will be queued. After the first run finishes, the next run will start.